# C++ Should this be easier?

Tags: c++, algorithm

long-time listener, first-time caller. I am relatively new to programming and was looking back at some of the code I wrote for an old lab. Is there an easier way to tell if a double is evenly divisible by an integer?

```
double num (//whatever);
int divisor (//an integer);
bool bananas;

   if(floor(num)!= num || static_cast<int>(num)%divisor != 0) {
     bananas=false;
   }   
   if(bananas==true)
         //do stuff;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a double is exactly divisible by 2, or if a double, when floored, is evenly divisible by 2?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083290/check-if-a-double-is-evenly-divisible-by-another-double-in-c

Comment: You can change `bananas==true` to `bananas` because it is a bool.  Just a suggestion but not really any improvement or anything.

Comment: Of course, it helps a little if you actually _set_ `bananas` to `true` at some point :-)

Comment: Or just remove `bananas` altogether...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is strange, and the checks are as well. The problem is that it makes little sense to speak about divisibility of a floating point number because floating point number are represented imprecisely in binary, and divisibility is about *exactitude*.

I encourage you to read this article, by David Goldberg: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://cr.yp.to/2005-590/goldberg.pdf). It is a bit long-winded, so you may appreciate this website, instead: [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

The truth is that `floor(num) == num` is a strange piece of code.

- `num` is a `double`
- `floor(num)` returns an `double`, close to an `int`

The trouble is that this does not check what you really wanted. For example, suppose (for the sake of example) that `5` cannot be represented exactly as a double, therefore, instead of storing `5`, the computer will store `4.999999999999`.

```
double num = 5; // 4.999999999999999
double floored = floor(num); // 4.0

assert(num != floored);
```

In general exact comparisons are *meaningless* for floating point numbers, because of rounding errors.

If you insist on using `floor`, I suggest to use `floor(num + 0.5)` which is better, though slightly biased. A better rounding method is the [Banker's rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) because it is unbiased, and the article references others if you wish. Note that the Banker's rounding is the baked in in `round`...

---

As for your question, first you need a `double` aware modulo: `fmod`, then you need to remember the *avoid exact comparisons* bit.

A first (naive) attempt:

```
// divisor is deemed non-zero
// epsilon is a constant

double mod = fmod(num, divisor); // divisor will be converted to a double

if (mod <= epsilon) { }
```

Unfortunately it fails one important test: the magnitude of `mod` depends on the magnitude of `divisor`, thus if `divisor` is smaller than `epsilon` to begin with, it will always be true.

A second attempt:

```
// divisor is deemed non-zero
double const epsilon = divisor / 1000.0;

double mod = fmod(num, divisor);

if (mod <= epsilon) { }
```

Better, but not quite there: `mod` and `epsilon` are signed! *Yes, it's a bizarre modulo, th sign of mod is the sign of num*

A third attempt:

```
// divisor is deemed non-zero
double const eps = fabs(divisor / 1000.0);

double mod = fabs(fmod(num, divisor));

if (mod <= eps) { }
```

Much better.

Should work fairly well too if `divisor` comes from an integer, as there won't be precision issues... or at least not too much.

**EDIT**: fourth attempt, by @ybungalobill

The previous attempt does not deal well with situations where `num/divisor` errors on the wrong side. Like `1.999/1.000` --> `0.999`, it's nearly `divisor` so we should indicate equality, yet it failed.

```
// divisor is deemed non-zero
mod = fabs(fmod(num/divisor, 1));

if (mod <= 0.001 || fabs(1 - mod) <= 0.001) { }
```

Looks like a never ending task eh ?

---

There is still cause for troubles though.

`double` has a limited precision, that is a limited number of digits that is representable (16 I think ?). This precision might be insufficient to represent an integer:

```
Integer n = 12345678901234567890;
double d = n; // 1.234567890123457 * 10^20
```

This *truncation* means it is impossible to map it back to its original value. This should not cause any issue with `double` and `int`, for example on my platform `double` is 8 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes, so it would work, but changing `double` to `float` or `int` to `long` could violate this assumption, oh hell!

*Are you sure you really need floating point, by the way ?*

Comment: There is still a problem. Since it's modular arithmetic, you need to check for `mod >= divisor-eps` too. Consider: `0.999 / 1.000 = 0.999`. Your test fails, but it shouldn't.

Comment: Also instead of computing `eps`, normalize to the [0,1) interval: `mod = fabs(fmod(num/divisor, 1))`. So `eps` and `divisor-eps` are now constants.

Comment: @ybungalobill: indeed, I had not thought of having a greater divisor.

Comment: Not greater, just errored to the wrong side. `fmod(1.999,1.000)=0.999` causes the same problem.

Comment: "floor(num) returns an int": `floor(num)` returns a double (or rather,
the same type as `num`, provided `num` is a floating point type).  As
for the rest, you're right that he should use `fmod`, but until you know
something about the input values, the rest of the attemps are just idle
speculation: in just about any context where comparing the results of
`fmod` to zero makes sense, an exact comparison is the correct solution,
and not all this business with exsilons, etc.

Comment: I was just looking through some of my old questions, and I would like to thank you for answering this one so thoroughly. I was in my first CS class at the time and I'll be graduating in a few short weeks. Your answer to this question was one of the first times I realized how much I had to learn.

Comment: @SegFaultsMcGee: I am glad this was useful to you, realizing there is something you don't know is the first step in improving :) Oh, and well done for your graduation!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above comments, I believe you can do this...

```
double num (//whatever);
int divisor (//an integer);
if(fmod(num, divisor) == 0) {
         //do stuff;
}
```

Comment: the cast from int to double should be implicit.  Else you can cast it explicitly without losing anything.  I'm a little fuzzy as to whether the above gives a warning without the cast, but casting can be as simple as a c-style `(double)divisor`

Comment: http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/37078/1954 Scroll down to where it talks about the example for "Blocking Implicit Conversion".  It says that the conversion will happen automatically.

Comment: @Matt: it is optimistic to believe you'll get an integer from `fmod`. You should never perform exact comparison on float point numbers, unless you wish to check if two numbers come from the same source. As soon as they have not been computed in the exact same way, beware of rounding errors.

Comment: Either the result **is** integer and there will be no rounding error or is not integer so `num` is not divisible by `divisor`

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Good point.  I looked at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083290/check-if-a-double-is-evenly-divisible-by-another-double-in-c But yeah, I think the problem lies in the fact that a floating point may not be represented as an exact integer value even if it "should" be because you initialized it to an "integer".  Obviously the accepted answer is way more comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it but why not do this?

```
if (floor(num) == num && !(static_cast<int>(num) % divisor)) {
    // do stuff...
}
```