# Print on screen at a certain string of numbers

Tags: c, math, for-loop

I want to extend the functionality of a part of a program that I'm working now..

Right now my code prints this on screen:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
...
1999
```

But I'm looking to do this: Putting the tens in text, without number. Also, numbering tens.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
ten 1
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
ten 2
21
22
...
1999
```

But with the functions that I know of C, I can't figure how to do.
Could do this with many ifs in the for, but do not want a code so extensive.

The code of the first output is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, j=2000;

        for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Very simple, and I want to keep that.

IN SIMPLE WORDS: All numbers ending in 0, should be print "ten x", instead the number...

Thank you.

Comment: What about 100?  Do you want to turn that into `ten ten`?

Comment: No. Keeping the line of "ten". I mean, the 100 has to be "ten 10". Same thing for the 1000.

Comment: @suddnely_me:  Wait, if you want only the tens place, then that means it would cycle between 0-9, not suddenly jump from 9 to 10.

Comment: Do you know about the '%' mod operator? It gives the remainder part instead of division, so 19 / 10 = 1, and 19 % 10 = 9. So any number % 10 will == 0 whenever it is a multiple of 10. That could be tested with an if.

Comment: @user1178392 A little curious...Why do you need this for?

Comment: @suddnely_me:  For brevity's sake:  Base 10 only goes through 0-9 in every place (ones, tens, hundreds, etc).  Saying that your tens place is now value 10 is inappropriate.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar is part of a experimental program for marketing.

Comment: @Makoto groundless without an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if a number `n` is divisible by ten, you use:

```
if ((n % 10) == 0) ...
```

That's the modulo operator which returns the remainder when `n` is divided by ten - numbers divisible by ten have a remainder of zero when you do that, all other numbers have a remainder of one through nine (at least in the non-negative space which is where you're working - it *may* be different for negative numbers but I'm not going to check since it's not relevant here).

To find which number you need to output with your `"ten"` string, simply divide `n` by ten.

So you print statement will become something like:

```
if ((i % 10) == 0)
    printf ("ten %d\n", i / 10);
else
    printf ("%d\n", i);
```

Making that change gives you the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
ten 1
11
12
:
1988
1989
ten 199
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
ten 200
```

which appears to be what you're after.

---

And just one other point, your output appears to stop at 1999 rather than 2000, despite the code. If that's what you really want, either change `j` to be 1999 or change the `for` statement to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: @suddnely_me, your answer is a block of code with no explanation. I prefer to provide more than that. I'm also not a big fan of expressions like `!i%10`, especially for beginners, when there are more readable alternatives with no downside (unless your compiler is truly brain-dead).

Comment: Nice! Just missed to replace the ten number by the text and no adding instead, but it helps a lot!

Comment: @paxdiablo you'd prefer `0 == (i % 10)` for beginners then? :)

Comment: Well, yes, except the other way around (`0` on the RHS). From teaching experience, students find it easier to understand equalities that the auto-conversion of boolean values to integers.

Comment: @paxdiablo the second output showed in my answer was the wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
      int i, j=2000;
      for( i = 1; i <= j; i++ )
      {
        if ( !i%10 ) // if i / 10 is an integer...
        {
          printf ("ten %d\n", i/10);
        } else
        {
          printf("%d\n", i);
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Fails on `i >= 100`.  Should give "0" not "10".

Comment: @Makoto can't see this condition.

Comment: `1250 % 10 = 0`, satisfying the condition.  `printf("ten %d\n", i/10)` will give `125`, not `5`.

Comment: Check my revision to my reply above.

Comment: @Makoto yes, and from my point of view it will be exact truth - 1250 is the 125th ten met.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to check IF the number is divisible by 10. Look here how to do that:
[Check if a double is evenly divisible by another double in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083290/check-if-a-double-is-evenly-divisible-by-another-double-in-c)

you could then check how many times it could be divided by 10 and print them out