# Determining if a Variable is Numerically an Integer in Python

Tags: python, variables, integer, modulo

I'm having an issue with determining if a variable is an integer. Not the variable type, but the actual value stored in the variable. I have tried using `variable % 1` as a test, but it does not seem to work. Here is the code I'm using for the test:

```
if ((xmax - x0)/h) % 1 == 0:
    pass
elif ((xmax - x0)/h) % 1 != 0:
    print "fail"
```

No matter what values are present for xmax, x0, and h, the statement always passes. For example, if they are 2.5 (2.5 % 1 = .5), it will still pass. I have tried if/else so i tried an else if statement as above and it does not work either.

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest of the answers. Can't believe I didn't think of it before!

Comment: [Check if a double is evenly divisible by another double in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2083290/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out whether a float number has integer value, you could call [`.is_integer() method`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
>>> 2.0 .is_integer()
True
>>> 2.5 .is_integer()
False
```

If `xmax, x0, h` are `int` instances then to test whether `(xmax - x0)` is evenly divisible by `h` i.e. whether the result of `truediv(xmax - x0,  h)` is an integer:

```
if (xmax - x0) % h == 0:
    pass
```

For float values, use [`math.fmod(x, y)` instead of `x % y` to avoid  suprising results](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fmod):

```
from math import fmod

if fmod(xmax - x0, h) == 0:
    pass
```

In most cases you might want to compare with some tolerance:

```
eps = 1e-12 * h
f = fmod(xmax - x0, h)
if abs(f) < eps or abs(f - h) < eps:
    pass
```

The result of `fmod` is exact by itself but the arguments may be not therefore the `eps` might be necessary.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know of these methods that are much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If both sides of the `/` are `int`, the result will be too - at least in Python 2.x. Thus your test for an integer value will always be true.

You can convert one side or the other to `float` and it will give a floating point result:

```
if (float(xmax - x0)/h) % 1 == 0:
```

You can also import the behavior from Python 3 that always returns a floating point result from a division:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple...

```
if isinstance(var, int):
    pass
else:
    fail
```

Comment: I tested it in a python shell and it returns False for 2.0. In my script, however, it always returns true whether it would be 2.0 or 2.5. None of the other methods are working inside of my script either. EDIT: I just didn't notice where it was printing fail.