# Given two doubles, how to determine if their quotient is exact?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, ieee-754

Given two `double` values, `p` and `q`, how can I determine if their quotient:

```
double result = p / q;
```

is an *exact* result in terms of the binary values of `p` and `q`?

That is, whether `result` is exactly equal to the mathematical division of `p` and `q`.

Clearly this is true for some values, such as `1.0 / 2.0` and false for others such as `1.0 / 5.0`, so I'm looking for an idiomatic and accurate way to separate the cases.

It seems like the floating point modulus `p % q == 0` *might* work, but I'm not sure!

Comment: Use a BigDecimal and compare the results?

Comment: @assylias How would you do the `1 / 3` case, for example?

Comment: Well, there is not way to store the mathematical result of 1./3. as this is not a limited number (can remember the exact name ;) ), you will get an approximation

Comment: @BeeOnRope BigDecimal division has an roundingMode==ROUND_UNNECESSARY option which throws an exception if the division result cannot be represented exactly with the chosen scale.

Comment: @AxelH yes can store that, for example you could have a fractional class that has a numerator and a denominator. The fact that `1 / 3 = 0.333...` is a repeating decimal (the name you were looking for) is mostly an artifact of our base-10 number system. If on Mars they use base 3 or base 6 or something it wouldn't repeat. Anyway, that's neither here nor there since we aren't talking about the decimal representation at all.

Comment: *"Given two `double` values"* How do you know the two values are exact to begin with, i.e. before dividing them?

Comment: @BeeOnRope But question is if `double` can store exact number, and `double` is base-2, not base-3, so that comment makes no sense for this question.

Comment: @Andreas - by the definition of my question :). The question talks about the mathematical values of the inputs `p` and `q`, which are "exact". In this context inexact is only something you could determine about the inputs from outside the system, e.g., because you know that an earlier operation was inexact. Here, ignore that, and deal only with the exact input values represented by the double. Regarding base-3, it has nothing to do with the question, only a response to AxelH. You may ignore it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Nice idea - I'm not sure how to define a scale that is "double-compatible" though.

Comment: @BeeOnRope but since you are using `double`, the value will be store in term of mantissa to represent a close value, not an exact one. So you can't store the result of 1./3. in a `double`. It would be a close match to be a finite number. There is no such way in term of binary computing to store a repeating decimal value. The only think you can do is use a `BigDecimal` that will store way more information using different storage system but even this is limited (well, you can still represent insane number without problem, but there is still a limit due to the array used).

Comment: @AxelH - perhaps I confused the issue by using `1 / 3` as an example. I know very well this can't be stored in an IEEE or java `double`, but the repeating fraction is totally besides the point. `1 / 5` which is equal to `0.2` also can't be stored exactly in a double, but doesn't repeat. Whether a fraction repeats is solely a function of the base of a number system. Stuff that repeats in one base may not repeat in another base. As it happens, anything that repeats in base-10 _also_ repeats in base-2 (due to 2 being a factor of 10), but again I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: @assylias The scale for `new BigDecimal(Double.MIN_VALUE)` is 1074. Anything that can be represented as a double must be an integer multiple of `Double.MIN_VALUE`. Scale 1075 should be sufficient to ensure that anything that throws an exception on the BigDecimal divide is not an exact double.

Comment: @Andreas - I tried to clarify the language in the question to make it clearer than the values of `p` and `q` are assumed to be correct, by adding that the division is in terms of the "binary values"of `p` and `q` (rather than say perhaps the values that a person might assume they have based on prior operations).

Comment: You could use `doubleToLongBits`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope You can get the exact bit representation of the value: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble-long-

Comment: @Bubletan - yes, I know - but how can that help me determine whether the division is _exact_?

Comment: Thinking out loud here, but is this problem equivalent to figuring out whether the quotient of mantissas requires no more than 53 bits to represent? i.e. conceptually you perform long division on the mantissas, and see if you still have a remainder after the 53rd bit.

Comment: @BeeOnRope You get three integers such that `s * m * 2^(e - 1075)` equals your double value. You have to check that `m` and `e` are exact.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That is a promising line of attack. There are some edge cases related to overflow, underflow, and sub-normal numbers to consider.

Comment: @Bubletan - I'm not sure how you plan to check if they are "exact". From one point of view they are exact in that their bit representation exactly defines them, but how to check if they exactly represent the quotient without writing a full-precision FP multiply in software?

Comment: I am not sure, but may be Math.fma(q, result, -p) === 0 will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `BigDecimal` to see if the division is exact:

```
private static boolean canDivideExact(double p, double q) {
  double r = p / q;
  BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(r);
  return d.multiply(new BigDecimal(q)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(p)) == 0;
}
```

For example:

```
System.out.println(canDivideExact(1, 2)); //true
System.out.println(canDivideExact(1, 3)); //false
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. Basically check the roundtrip, exactly, and see if it equals the dividend. I guess `BigDecimal` is terribly slow for this purpose though (have to benchmark)...

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes it's going to be slow (~ 30x slower than the modulus). I see around 2 microseconds per call on my reasonably fast PC.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Also, not a proof, but I've run my method vs. your modulus method on 10s of millions of doubles and they returned the same result each time.

Comment: Yeah, [this seems promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083290/check-if-a-double-is-evenly-divisible-by-another-double-in-c) in that it indicates that `fmod` is the right way to do this in C, and apparently `%` in Java is modeled after `fmod`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways that don't involve using `BigDecimal`. As written, neither will work for subnormals, but if you can avoid subnormals, underflow and overflow, both should give good results. I expect that both methods could be adapted to work for the subnormal case, but I haven't thought about how to do so.

1. Any finite nonzero `double` `x` can be written uniquely in the form `x = m 2^e` for integers `e` and `m` with `m` *odd*. Let's call `m` the **odd part** of `x`. Now given two nonzero finite doubles `x` and `y`, and assuming that overflow and underflow are avoided, `x / y` is exactly representable if and only if the odd part of `x` is an integer multiple of the odd part of `y`. We can check that integer multiple condition using `%`, so all that's left is finding a way to compute the odd part. In C or Python, I'd use [`frexp`](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/math_h/frexp.php), throw away the exponent, and repeatedly multiply the fraction by two until it's an integer, but `frexp` doesn't appear to be available in Java. However, Java does have `Math.getExponent`, which would provide the exponent part of `frexp`, and then `Math.scalb` can be used to get the fraction.
2. After computing `x / y` and getting a (possibly rounded) result `z`, you can multiply `y` by `z` using double-double arithmetic (via Veltkamp splitting and Dekker multiplication), and check that the result is exactly equal to `x`. This should be more efficient that the equivalent method using `BigDecimal`, since we know in advance that we don't need more than double the usual floating-point precision to contain the result.

I'm afraid I'm not fluent enough in Java to give code, but here's code in Python that it should be straightforward to adapt to Java. (Note that Python's `float` type matches Java's `double` on a typical machine; in theory, Python doesn't require IEEE 754, but in practice it's almost inevitable that the Python `float` format will be IEEE 754 binary64.)

If anyone wants to steal this code, convert it to Java, and put it into an answer, I'll happily upvote.

```
import math

def odd_part(x):
    """
    Return an odd integer m (as a double) such that x can be written
    in the form m * 2**e for some exponent e. The exponent e is not
    returned.
    """
    fraction, exponent = math.frexp(x)

    # here fraction * 2**53 is guaranteed to be an integer, so we
    # don't need to loop more than 53 times.
    while fraction % 1.0 != 0.0:  # or in Python, use the is_integer method.
        fraction *= 2.0
    return fraction


# Constant used in Veltkamp splitting.
C = float.fromhex('0x1.0000002000000p+27')

def split(x):
    """
    Split a double x into pieces x_hi, x_lo, each
    expressible with 26 bits of precision.

    Algorithm due to Veltkamp.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : float
        Finite float, such that C*x does not overflow. Assumes IEEE 754
        representation and arithmetic, with round-ties-to-even rounding
        mode.

    Returns
    -------
    l, h : float
        l and h are both representable in 26 bits of precision, and
        x = l + h.

    """
    # Idea of proof: without loss of generality, we can reduce to the case
    # where 0.5 < x < 1 (the case where x is a power of 2 is straightforward).
    # Write rnd for the floating-point rounding operation, so p = rnd(Cx) and q
    # = rnd(x-p).
    #
    # Now let e and f be the errors induced by the floating-point operations,
    # so
    #     p = Cx + e
    #     q = x - p + f
    #
    # Then it's easy to show that:
    #
    #  2**26 < |Cx| < 2**28, so p is a multiple of 2**-26 and |e| <= 2**-26.
    #  2**26 <= p - x <= 2**27, so q is a multiple of 2**-26 and |f| <= 2**-27.
    #  h = p + q is exactly representable, equal to x + f
    #  h <= 1, and h is a multiple of 2**-26, so h has precision <= 26.
    #  l = x - h is exactly representable, equal to f.
    #  |f| <= 2**-27, and f is a multiple of 2**-53, so f has precision <= 26.

    p = C * x
    q = x - p
    h = p + q
    l = x - h
    return l, h


def exact_mult(x, y):
    """
    Multiply floats x and y exactly, expressing the result as l + h,
    where h is the closest float to x * y and l is the error.

    Algorithm is due to Dekker.

    Assumes that x and y are finite IEEE 754 binary64 floats.

    May return inf or nan due to intermediate overflow.

    May raise ValueError on underflow or near-underflow.

    If both results are finite, then we have equality:

       x * y = h + l

    """
    # Write |x| = M * 2**e, y = |N| * 2**f, for some M and N with
    # M, N <= 2**53 - 1. Then xy = M*N*2**(e+f). If e + f <= -1075
    # then xy < (2**53 - 1)**2 * 2**-1075 < 2**-969 (1 - 2**-53),
    # which is exactly representable.
    # Hence the rounded value of |xy| is also < 2**-969.

    # So if |xy| >= 2**-969, and |xy| isn't near overflow, it follows that x*y
    # *can* be expressed as the sum of two doubles: 

    # If |xy| < 2**-969, we can't guarantee it, and we raise ValueError.

    h = x * y

    if abs(h) < 2**-969 and x != 0.0 and y != 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot guarantee exact result.")

    xl, xh = split(x)
    yl, yh = split(y)
    return -h + xh * yh + xh * yl + xl * yh + xl * yl, h


def division_exact_method_1(x, y):
    """
    Given nonzero finite not-too-large not-too-small floats x and y,
    return True if x / y is exactly representable, else False.
    """
    return odd_part(x) % odd_part(y) == 0


def division_exact_method_2(x, y):
    """
    Given nonzero finite not-too-large not-too-small floats x and y,
    return True if x / y is exactly representable, else False.
    """
    z = x / y
    low, high = exact_mult(y, z)
    return high == x and low == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `p % q == 0` solution works: it checks whether `p` can be *evenly* divided by `q`, that is, whether `p / q` is a whole number. For example, `1.0 % 2.0 == 1.0`, although it can be exactly represented as a double: `1.0 / 2.0 == 0.5`.

Interestingly, IEEE 754, which also serves as the basis for Java's floating point implementation, has exactly what you need. If a floating point operation yields an inprecise result, an exception (in the IEEE sense) is raised, which by default updates a status word, so you can always check whether a result was precise by checking this status word. Unfortunately, Java chose not to make that status accessible.

If you want to keep using Java, you either have to use assylia's `BigDecimal`-based solution, or maybe try to access those error flags through JNI: in C (C99 onwards) you can test if the result was exact with `fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT)`. I don't know if that will work, though.